# Limited completeness and restricted quantifiers

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a first order language with no constant or operation symbols. $L$ also has a relation symbol $R$ of arity $2$. Let $T$ be a Godelian set of formulas. Let $Q^1,Q^2$ be two formulas. The only free variable of $Q^1$ is $v_1$ and the only free variable of $Q^2$ is $v_2$. $v_1$ does not occur inside $Q^2$ and $v_2$ does not occur inside $Q^1$. It is given that: $$\exists v_1(Q^1),\exists v_2(Q^2)\in T...(1)$$
It is also given that for every formula $P^1$ with only $v_1$ as its free variable, the following holds:
$$\forall v_1 (Q^1\rightarrow P^1)\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_1(Q^1\rightarrow (\lnot P^1))\in T...(2)$$

Informally, this means that if there is an object satisfies $Q^1$, then we know everything about it.

Similarly, for every  formula $P^2$ with only $v_2$ as its free variable, the following holds:
$$\forall v_2 (Q^2\rightarrow P^2)\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_2(Q^2\rightarrow (\lnot P^2))\in T...(3)$$

I really think that the following must be true but I am unable to prove it:
$$\forall v_1\forall v_2 [(Q^1\land Q^2)\rightarrow R(v_1v_2)]\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_1\forall v_2 [(Q^1\land Q^2)\rightarrow \big(\lnot R(v_1v_2)\big)]\in T...(4)$$

I would like to see a proof for the above statement.

Thank you

---

A Godelian set is a maximally consistent set of formulas that contains all logical axioms, tautologies, and is closed under modus ponens, and the generalization rule of $\forall$. This definition is used in Manin's book and I thought it was standard.

Comment: Is the question unclear or uninteresting ?

Comment: It needs a better title for one.

Comment: @Memming Yes, but I can't think of a better title

Comment: I've attempted to give a more incisive title.  I don't know the answer, but my intuition is that it is false and that a model can be used to prove it so.

Comment: @hardmath Why is your intuition that it is false, I have the intuition that it is true. I will still try the ideas given in the answers below

Comment: I don't know the phrase Goedelian set of formulas, but it seems to mean a complete theory.  That would be clearer if we spoke of sentences rather than formulas, but with the requirement of closure under Generalization, the distinction almost seems moot.

Comment: So I have in mind that $T$ amounts to sentences that are true in some fixed model. The intuition is then similar to what the two earlier Answers express.  We might have a model in which all the elements are interchangeable.  However knowing the satisfiability of a formula with one free variable does suffice to determine the truth of formulas with two free variables, which is how I understood your Question.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "does *not* suffice" in the last Comment.  Perhaps the distinction regular and strongly regular graphs is analogous, or more to the point, vertex transitive but not edge transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. I will give the counterexample below.

Consider the first-order language $L=\{\equiv\}$ that only has the binary relation symbol $\equiv$. Let $M:=\{0,1\}$. We define an interpretation $\Phi$ of $L$ in $M$ as follows:
$$\Phi(\equiv):=\{(a,a)|a\in M\}$$
Since $L$ does not have any constant or operation symbols, the above line completely determines our interpretation $\Phi$. Now consider $f:M\rightarrow M$ that sends $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $0$. Clearly, $f$ is a bijection.

Let $Var$ denote the set of variables in our alphabet.

**Claim1:** For every formula $P$ in $L$ and every interpretation $\Gamma:Var\rightarrow M$, we have $|P|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=|P|_{\Phi}(f\Gamma)$

**Proof:** Induct on the length of the formula $P$. Let $\Gamma$ be our interpretation function of the variable symbols. Base: $P$ is atomic. Case 1: $P$ is "$\equiv(x_1x_2)$" and $x_1,x_2$ are two variable symbols (possibly $x_1$ is the symbol as $x_2$). Since $f$ is a bijection, therefore $\Gamma(x_1)=\Gamma(x_2)$ iff $f\Gamma(x_1)=f\Gamma(x_2)$. Hence, $(\Gamma(x_1),\Gamma(x_2))\in \Phi(\equiv)$ iff $(f\Gamma(x_1),f\Gamma(x_2))\in \Phi(\equiv)$. Thus, $|P|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=|P|_{\Phi}(f\Gamma).$ The proof of the induction step is trivial and follows immediately from the recursive definition of $|P|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)$. $\square$

Now let $T$ be the subset of the formulas of $L$ that is deined by $T:=\{P|\text{For every interpretation of the variable symbols $\Gamma$, we have $|P|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=1$}\}$. It is a theorem that the set of true statements about a structure form a Godelian set. Hence, $T$ is Godelian.

Now using ideas from the other two answers.

Now set $Q^1,Q^2$ to be $v_1=v_1,v_2=v_2$. By looking at our interpretation $\Phi$, we can see clearly that $\exists v_1(Q^1),\exists v_2(Q^2)\in T$.

**Claim 2:** For every formula $P^1$ that $v_1$ as its only free variable, Either $\forall v_1[ P^1]\in T$ or $\forall v_1[\lnot P^1]\in T$

Proof: Suppose the first option does not hold, therefore there is some variable interpretation $\Gamma$ such that $| P^1|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=0$. Hence, $| \not P^1|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=1$. Using Claim 1, we get $| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(f\Gamma)=1$ as well. Now for any variable interpretation $\Theta$, either $\Theta(v_1)=\Gamma(v_1)$ or $\Theta(v_1)=f\Gamma(v_1)$ (because the size of our model is two and $f$ does not have any fixed points). Since $v_1$ is the only free variable of $P^1$. Thus, either $| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(\Theta)=| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(\Gamma)=1$ or $| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(\Theta)=| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(f\Gamma)=1$. Hence, $| \lnot P^1|_{\Phi}(\Theta)$ is always $1$ for any variable interpretation $\Theta$. Thus, $|\forall v_1( \lnot P^1)|_{\Phi}(\Theta)=1$ for every $\Theta$. Thus, $\forall v_1( \lnot P^1) \in T$.  $\square$

Since, $\forall v_1(Q^1)\in T$ one use claim 2 to show that:

$$\forall v_1 (Q^1\rightarrow P^1)\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_1(Q^1\rightarrow (\lnot P^1))\in T$$
Similarly, one can also show that:

$$\forall v_2 (Q^2\rightarrow P^2)\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_2(Q^2\rightarrow (\lnot P^2))\in T$$

However, by looking at the model $M$ and the interpretation $\Phi$ we can clearly see that:

$$\forall v_1\forall v_2 [(Q^1\land Q^2)\rightarrow \equiv(v_1v_2)]\not\in T \,\,\text{and}\,\,\forall v_1\forall v_2 [(Q^1\land Q^2)\rightarrow \big(\lnot \equiv(v_1v_2)\big)]\not\in T$$

---

Now we can isolate a certain interesting concept in the above proof and make the following definition:

Let $L$ be a first order language with relation symbols only. Let $\Phi$ be an interpretation of $L$ in $M$. We say that a bijection $f:M\rightarrow M$ is a **model automorphism** iff for every relation symbol $R$ in $L$ with arity $r$, we have the following:

For every $m_1,m_2,...,m_r\in M$:  $$(m_1,m_2,...,m_r)\in \Phi(R) \,\,\, \text{iff} \,\,\,(f(m_1),f(m_2),...,f(m_r))\in \Phi(R)$$

Clearly, the set of model automorphisms of $M$ forms a group under function composition. I will come back and add to this post when I have time.

Comment: @DanulG I proved the part of your solution which you did not give a proof for. It is related to what I would call model "automorphisms"

Comment: @hardmath The answer is no. I have a complete proof now.

Comment: Thanks for the other answers

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Let $Q_1$ be $v_1=v_1$ and similarly for $Q_2$. Consider a structure $A$ where $R(x, y)$ sometimes holds and sometimes fails, and let $T$ be the set of all statements true in $A$.

Comment: Hi Dr. Wafik ! $Q_1$ defined to be $v_1=v_1$ does not satisfy: For every formula $P^1$ with only $v_1$ as its free variable, the following holds:
$$\forall v_1 (Q^1\rightarrow P^1)\in T \,\,\text{or}\,\,\forall v_1(Q^1\rightarrow (\lnot P^1))\in T$$, does it ?

Comment: In my question, $(1),(2),(3)$ are givens and $(4)$ is what is required to prove.

Comment: You're right. I was sloppy. The construction of the structure needs the following: R forms a cycle, and all other relations always hold. Now every element satisfy the same formulas with one free variable.

Comment: What does $R$ cyclic mean ? Does it mean that $A\models {\{\forall x\forall y [R(xy)\rightarrow R(yx)]\}}$

Answer (score 1):

I believe the statement you want is false.

Let $L=\{R\}$. Given a sentence $\varphi$ of L, let $\varphi{'}$ be the sentence obtained by replacing each occurrence of $R$ in $\varphi$ by $=$. Let $\psi_{\varphi}:=\varphi \iff \varphi{'}$.

Now let $T_{0}$ = The theory of equality $\cup$ there are exactly two elements $\cup \{\psi_{\varphi}:=\varphi \iff \varphi{'}: \varphi \text{ is an L sentence with R in it}\}$. Let $M\models{T_{0}}$. Let $T=Th(M)$. Let $Q^{1}:=v_{1}=v_{1}$, $Q^{2}:=v_{2}=v_{2}$. Now it is clear that the conclusion you want isn't true.

Now let $P^{1}$ be a formula with just $v_{1}$ free. I'm pretty sure that we can prove $\forall{v_{1}}(Q^{1}\implies{P^{1}})\in{T}$ or $\forall{v_{1}}(Q^{1}\implies{\neg P^{1}})\in{T}$. by an induction on the complexity of $P^{1}$: However it is more complicated than I was hoping it would be.

Comment: Thanks for your help. A Godelian set is a maximally consistent set of formulas that contains all logical axioms, tautologies, and is closed under modus ponens, and the generalization rule of first order logic. This definition is used in Manin's book and I thought it was standard.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll edit my answer but I think that this still gives you what you are looking for, or is it something different?

Comment: I will read you ranswer, thank you.

Comment: I do not agree when you say: "I'm pretty sure that we can prove $\forall{v_{1}}(Q^{1}\implies{P^{1}})\in{T}$ or $\forall{v_{1}}(Q^{1}\implies{\neg P^{1}})\in{T}$."

Comment: Informally, if we only know that $c_1=c_1$ for some some constant in our model, we may not be able to determine everything about $c_1$ I really think counterexamples are easy to find

Comment: Let $L=\{\in\}$. For example, if you let $T$ be any Godelian set containing all axioms of ZFC and all logical axioms of $=$... It does not hold that $\forall v_1[v_1=v_1\rightarrow v_1=\emptyset]\in T$ or $\forall v_1[v_1=v_1\rightarrow \lnot(v_1=\emptyset)]\in T$. Since $\forall v_1[v_1=v_1]$ is true and $T$ is Godelian, it will follow that $\forall v_1[v_1=\emptyset]\in T$ or $\forall v_1[v_1\not=\emptyset]\in T$

Comment: The idea behind this example is that the language with only equality is very weak. It can only say a few things. Your examples where things go wrong are lot more complicated (you have constants in your language and $ZFC$ is about as complicated as you can get (See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_theory). Here things are much simpler: there is only one atomic formula with only $v_{1}$ free: $v_{1}=v_{1}$. So the result you want is clearly established for atomic $P^{1}$. Now do induction on the complexity of $P^{1}$ and the result should follow (you need to do some work though)

Comment: Ahh. I see. OK I will try this idea.

Comment: Tthanks for your answer +1